# How to define the size of paragraph indent?

Tags: indentation

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 

Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip 
ex ea commodo consequat. 

Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore 
eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 

\end{document}
```

Doing like this I want to get text with 1 cm indent in the beginning of each paragraph. Default indent is smaller. How to define the size?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Set the `\parindent` length to the desired value:

```
\setlength\parindent{1cm}
```

A complete example using your code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\setlength\parindent{1cm}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 

Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip 
ex ea commodo consequat. 

Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore 
eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 

\end{document}
```

[image]